# WKWebView height constraint causes constraints error

Tags: swift, constraints, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView inside a UIView.

Those are the constraints:

```
webContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
webContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
webContainerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true


contentWKWebView.navigationDelegate = self
contentWKWebView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.webContainerView.leftAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
contentWKWebView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.webContainerView.rightAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
contentWKWebView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.webContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
contentWKWebView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.webContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
webViewHeightConstraint = contentWKWebView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
webViewHeightConstraint?.isActive = true // causes error
```

I have to set an initial height size for the WKWebView or else, the auto-adjust height to fit the content won't work.

This is the code for auto-adjust the height:

```
extension MyCell: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
            self.webViewHeightConstraint?.constant = height as! CGFloat
        })
    }
}
```

The UIView and the WKWebView are subviews of a UITableViewCell.

Any idea how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason you are not providing a topAnchor to self for your webContainerView ?

Comment: @ekscrypto There is a topAnchor for the webContainerView which is set in the view that comes before it. I set there stackView.bottomAnchor = webContainer.topAnchor. Don't you think the problem is for contentWKWebView itself?

Comment: So... if I get this right... you have a UITableView containing several cells, one of those cells contain a UIStackView and a UIView, and that UIView contains a webContainerView which itself contains a WKWebView ?  Sounds overly complex for some reason...

Comment: @ekscrypto Well, how would you present 20 (or more) cells with HTML (my own HTML, not from the web)? You think I should give up the TableView and use UISCrollView? Can you think of a straight answer to the height issue?

Comment: I'd rather not make any architectural decision based on the little information here! :D   Do you have any more information you could share like the actual console errors shown? Did you follow the steps from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html ?

Comment: contentWKWebView.bottomAnchor constraint priority must set to a number lower than the priority of the height constraint.